# In javascript, what is a constructor? And what isn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor

I'm using a plugin for jQuery. It works great in webkit, but when I try it in firefox I get the following firefox error:

```
google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
$('.to, .from').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
```

Here is all the jquery:

```
$('.to, .from').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder, {
mapkey: 'ABQIAAAAbnvDoAoYOSW2iqoXiGTpYBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQNumU68AwGqjbSNF9YO8NokKst8w', 
selectFirst: false,
minChars: 3,
cacheLength: 50,
width: 235,
scroll: true,
scrollHeight: 330
});
```

What's a constructor and howcome firefox is pointing it out to me?

http://dev.resihop.nu is the site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any native function may be called as a constructor (even if it wasn't designed to be). Anything that's not callable also cannot be a constructor. eg `new 3` gives the same error.

In your page, `google.maps.Geocoder` is simply `undefined`, which certainly isn't going to help. Looking at Google's [maps script](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false) it's failing to load the Geocoder module because it's using `document.write` to do so, a method that has to be run from a `<script>` included in the HTML document at parse time, not imported by use of DOM scripting as you're doing here.

It certainly doesn't expect to be run from a page loaded via client-side XSLT. This is going to give you lots of browser problems and zero SEO presence. What is the purpose of this craziness?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the spec says that `new` invokes the `[[Construct]]` internal method, while a plain function call uses `[[Call]]`.  Now that said I have no idea what sort of thing would have one but not the other, but perhaps some things exposed via the global namespace might - what does `new setTimeout()` do?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said *native* function. :-) Actually I think per ECMA262-5, *built-in* functions that aren't meant to be used as constructors shouldn't have a `[[Construct]]`, and so should `TypeError`. What actually happens is highly browser- and function-dependent. Opera seems to get it right. Chrome calls `new encodeURIComponent('x')` as a constructor (returning the new Object as the returned string is not an object). Firefox varies (eg `new setTimeout` gives a different internal error; `new encodeURIComponent('x')` returns the string!). In summary: argh!

Comment: Thanks for the info, although I'm not sure how to work it out yet, but you got me started atleast!

Comment: asfor the frontend xslt, it's really not my desciscion, I'd prefer to run it backend. However I have had no other browserproblems with it, our plan is to push backend-generated html to any robot or other none-identifiable reader of the page.

Comment: I'm not certain that I understand the problem, but as far as I can understand, you mean that it doesnt work because I'm using the .ready-function, however it works with this sample code: http://dev.resihop.nu/ui.demo.html

Comment: No, the problem is the inclusion of the script via weird and unexpected means (the XSLT stuff). Google's script expects to be run via a direct `<script>` tag in an HTML page; it uses `document.write` which is never going to work with client-side XSLT. As your sample code is in plain HTML, it works there. It might be possible to hack a copy of the script to make it load in a different way, but that's not going to be much fun and may break when Google update it. I would seriously push to lose the client-side XSLT.

Answer (score 6):

A constructor is the function (which returns an object of the function name's type) that is invoked when you use `new` in conjunction with that function's name, such as:

```
function Person(name, age) {
   //blah
}

var me = new Person("Jacob", 20);
```

Comment: `new` will cause the given function to be called as a constructor even if you omit the trailing `()`; this is one of JavaScript's odd syntax quirks. The problem here is more basic than lack of parentheses.

Comment: This isn't passing a reference. It is calling the constructor with the `new` keyword and passing zero arguments. Parentheses are not required for constructors that don't require arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You msut use google.maps.geocoder like this:

```
$('.to, .from').geo_autocomplete(new google.maps.Geocoder({
  mapkey:'ABQIAAAAbnvDoAoYOSW2iqoXiGTpYBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxQNumU68AwGqjbSNF9YO8NokKst8w', 
  selectFirst: false,
  minChars: 3,
  cacheLength: 50,
  width: 235,
  scroll: true,
  scrollHeight: 330
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate an object, e.g. create an instance of an object, the constructor is the first method that is called within your object.

When you're calling

```
new google.maps.Geocoder
```

...you are attempting instantiate a parameterless constructor of the object by using the new keyword.  In this case, Geocoder is not a class that can be instantiated without parameters, or at all.